# extJs - populate grid with array of arrays

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-stores

I have an array of persons, each person has an array of contacts. The data is in json format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7900,
    "position": "Tillitsvalgt",
    "person": {
      "id": 1000001,
      "lastName": "Andrushko",
      "contacts": [
        {
          "id": 1000001,
          "personId": 1000001,
          "type": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Mobile phone"
          },
          "value": "25417"
        },
        {
          "id": 1000002,
          "personId": 1000001,
          "type": {
            "id": 35,
            "name": "Mobile phone"
          },
          "value": "945417"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7900,
    "position": "Tillitsvalgt",
    "person": {
      "id": 1000001,
      "lastName": "Andrushko",
      "contacts": [
        {
          "id": 1000001,
          "personId": 1000001,
          "type": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Mobile phone"
          },
          "value": "25417"
        },
        {
          "id": 1000002,
          "personId": 1000001,
          "type": {
            "id": 35,
            "name": "Mobile phone"
          },
          "value": "945417"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to display two grids, first one with persons and the second one with contacts for selected person. I have created two models:

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            mapping: 'person.lastName',
            name: 'lastName'
        }
    ],

    hasMany: [
        {
            associationKey: 'person.contacts',
            model: 'Contact',
            name: 'contacts'
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'MemberServlet?operation=get',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

and a model for contacts:

```
Ext.define('Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            mapping: 'type.name',
            name: 'type'
        },
        {
            name: 'value'
        }
    ],

    belongsTo: {
        model: 'Person'
    }
});
```

In such configuration my second grid displays contacts for all persons, I want it to display only for selected person. How can I do it?

Comment: One store for more than one grid is not a good approach.

Comment: @DarinKolev: It's ok if you have one store definition for multiple grids. But depending on scenario you made need multiple instances:
Ext.define('myKindOfStore');
var store1 = Ext.create('myKindOfStore');
var store2 = Ext.create('myKindOfStore');

Comment: @Oleg: See my comment to Darin: Create an instance for each grid and then use events and filters. When selection on gridA changes (re)filter gridB.